# Can I find the Fourier series expression from given terms?

Tags: fourier, signal-theory

[image]I found the fundamental frequency, and all the harmonic components (an, bn), but is it possible to find the fundamental expression of an ,bn or cn?
-The last part of the question-

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, you must have used an expression to get \$ a_n\$ and \$ b_n\$. Also, what's \$ c_n\$?

Comment: Cn is the complex form of the series...but the question wants the revers steps, it gives me an and bn; and i must find the expression

Comment: Do you mean writing the harmonics in the form \$a_n sin \:(n\:\omega t)\$?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find a mathematical expression for the signal, like f(t) = ...?

Comment: It would help if you added to your question the formula in which an, bn and cn fit in. It is unclear what these are referring to.

Comment: to be clear, if \ b11 = (3pi/17)\$ , \ b1 = (3pi/2) ,\ b3 = (-5pi/6)\$ and \ b9 = (3pi/5). How would i find the formula of \ bn\$?-the integral resut-

Comment: It would be clearer if you gave the complete question, rather than drip-feeding it.

Answer (score 1):

For the exponential Fourier series, use the identities:

\$cos(n\omega t)= \dfrac{e^{jn\omega t}+e^{-jn\omega t}}{2}\$

\$sin(n\omega t)= \dfrac{e^{jn\omega t}-e^{-jn\omega t}}{j2}\$

with \$n=1;\:n=3;\:n=11\$, and \$\omega=\frac{4\pi}{3}\$